# Select specific elements from list of files

Tags: r, list, file

I have two list of files in R, list 1 has a length of 623, list 2 has a length around 1000000. The 623 files from list 1 are also in list 2, however list 2 contains a lot of other files, furthermore the two lists are in different directories so they do not have the same basename.
E.g.

"D:\Soroe\AerodyneSP\161008_to_161211_same_container\Data/161009/161009_005301_001_CAL.spe"

"D:\Soroe\AerodyneSP\161008_to_161211_same_container\Playback\Spec/161009/161009_005301_001_CAL.spe"

These two files are the same but the upper one is from list 1 and the lower one is from list 2.

What I want is to find the 623 files in list 2 that has the same files names as list 1.

Comment: Why wouldn't this just be `flist2[flist2 %in% flist1]`?

Comment: Thanks, but they the two lists are not in the same directory, so eventough the file names are the same, the path to the files differs, so I dont think the command  would work

Comment: Use `basename`?

Comment: Then you just demonstrated why it is always best to present example data and code. I'll reverse my close vote (for vagueness) when you improve this question to SO standards. See [MCVE] and [edit]

Comment: Thanks, combining basenames and flist2[flist2 %in% flist1] seems to work